# How to assign different colors to items in JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JComboBox and have 10 string items added in it.
I want to assign different colors to each item.
How i can achive this?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example in Chandru's answer looks like a lot of code so I can understand why you're asking for an easier solution.  However, if you subclass **`DefaultListCellRenderer`** a lot of the work is done for you, as this renderer is a subclass of `JLabel`.

```
JList list = ... // Create JList

// Install custom renderer.
list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    // Request superclass to render the JLabel.
    Component ret = super.getListCellRenderer(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

    // Now conditionally override background if cell isn't selected.
    if (!isSelected) {
      String s = String.valueOf(value);

      if (s.equals("Foo")) {
        ret.setBackground(Color.RED);
      } else {
        ret.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
      }
    }

    return ret;
  }
});
```

Comment: You can upvote this answer (and some of the other answers) if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a custom list cell renderer.  Look into [this how-to](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But is there any easier way?
I tried setForeground() after each addItem() but it do not work.
I don't know why.

Comment: Did you set the foreground within the renderer component?

Answer (score 1):

You must implement a new [ListCellRenderer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) ,which will be used by your combobox, through [setRenderer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setRenderer(javax.swing.ListCellRenderer)), to render properly your objects.

You can extend [BasicComboBoxRenderer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicComboBoxRenderer.html) to avoid reconding everything.